# Lubuntu loader fails to install GRUB2 in /target/, can't find boot-repair

Tags: grub2, lubuntu, boot-repair

I've been trying to install Lubuntu 16.10 on an HP Pavilion dm1 notebook (previously had Ubuntu on it). It fails to load grub every time and won't boot. I've searched the threads and tried many of the fixes, none have worked. I'm a newbie, so the most promising seemed to be the Boot-repair utility but I can't find it through `apt-get` or the method described on the Ubuntu documentation website [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-repair). I've included a couple pictures in case it sheds light on the situation. I've lost WiFi connectivity for whatever reason, but have Internet connectivity through a USB tether to my phone. I'm not really in a position to make more live USB drives at the moment.

Actually I can't post pictures at my reputation level, first post.

Comment: You can still include links to arbitrary web resources (e. g. pictures) in your question – though not more than a few. After that you'll have to format them as code with a `\`` on each side to circumvent the spam detection.

Answer (score 0):

I have found that by using the command line (terminal) to install every thing, it works better. Go to   http://www.howtogeek.com/114884/how-to-repair-grub2-when-ubuntu-wont-boot/   Follow instructions on web page and you should be up and running in no time.  You can usually find command line input code, to install everything you need to install! I have found that by using the words (how to install >your program here< using command line, in your search box works great! Linux is GREAT :-)